# SSO Authentication and Authorization

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on, cas

I am a little bit confused about the terms of authorization and authentication. I know what each term means but combined with different Single Sign-On services I've got some problems with a consistent terminology.

What I am confused about is that, for example, CAS ( Central Authentication Service ) is meant to be used for authentication AND authorizationk. For me authorization would mean, that there is a functionality in the implementations, so the server decides if the user gets access to a different service or not.
But as I've seen, for example in CAS, that authorization for them is only sending different user attributes to the service and it decides whether the user can access or not. But is CAS then really providing a authorization? Is this not just authentication and then giving some attributes to another service which then decides whether the user can pass or not?

tl;dr:
Is sending user attributes to a given 3rd party web service so he can decide whether the user gets a login session or not already authorization by the SSO service, or is it just helping the 3rd party service to manage authorization ( so the SSO service does NOT provide authorization, just authentication) ?

Answer (score 0):

`CAS` **is not** an authorization service. it is build to support authentication with single sign on and it can not authorize anything, the only authorization part it can help u with is to send u some user roles as attribute and u can use those roles as `role authorization'. for more than role authorization u need to implement your own authorization system (maybe embedded in the application that is using cas as authentication?)